# rails render angular component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I have a Question regarding ruby on rails (backend) and angularjs (Frontend).

I implemented this password recovery function, which i found on railscast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

My problem is, i want to use angularjs on the frontend, but after the user requested and clicked on his reset url(inside mail), rails is looking for edit.html.erb and throws a "Missing template" error

How can i tell rails to render a angularjs component when the edit action is fired up.

Version:
ruby  2.0.0;
rails 4.2.4